# Is there anyway to disable viewCell highlight in TableView Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, tableview

I am trying to make a form using TableView viewCell. Everything is working fine but I want to disable highlight feature on that viewCell. I could not find anything on internet and there is nothing related to this on Xamarin documentation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the highlighting feature you are talking about is part of the native control that the cell  or list/table view uses to render the Xamarin.Forms TableView/ViewCell, so you have to make a [custom renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/), or use an [effect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/) to modify properties on the native control. I personally am more used to custom renderers than effects, so that is what I will use in the following example.

I can give you examples for iOS and Android, but I would have to dig in to UWP for a solution for the UWP platform.

On Android, you can set the highlight color to transparant on the native Android ListView that is used to render the Xamarin.Forms TableView. Just add a C# code file to your Android project and add the following code, changing the namespace as appropriate for your solution:

```
using Android.Content;
using TableViewSamples.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TableView), typeof(CustomTableViewRenderer))]
namespace TableViewSamples.Droid
{
    class CustomTableViewRenderer : TableViewRenderer
    {
        public CustomTableViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TableView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                // This sets the highlight color to transparent for all cells in the Android native ListView:
                Control.Selector = new Android.Graphics.Drawables.ColorDrawable(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On iOS, the highlight color is set on the cell class, so you need to make a custom renderer for the ViewCell rather than the TableView:

```
using TableViewSamples.iOS;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ViewCell), typeof(CustomViewCellRenderer))]

namespace TableViewSamples.iOS
{
    class CustomViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
        {
            var cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
            // This sets the highlight color to transparent for each UITableViewCell in the iOS native UITableView:
            cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
            return cell;
        }

    }
}
```

Note that these replace the default renderer for all of the Xam.Forms TableView istances in your Xam.Forms Android app, and for all of the ViewCell instances in your Xam.Forms iOS app. If you need to do this only for some TableView and ViewCell, then you need to subclass TableView and ViewCell and make the renderers refer to those subclasses in the ExportRenderer attribute, e.g.:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ViewCellSubClass), typeof(CustomViewCellRenderer))]
```

and

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TableViewSubClass), typeof(CustomTableViewRenderer))]
```